# How to refresh the vue component from method

Tags: vue.js, components, vuetify.js

I want to refresh the vue component from method, which should go through all the vue lifecycle hook events. Could some one please help to achieve this

I was v-if from the following link, but the lifecycle hooks are not triggered
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to the component like this

```
<my-component :key="identifier" />
```

And in the data add a variable identifier

```
  data() {
    return {
      identifier: +new Date()
    };
  },
  methods: {
    refreshComponent() {
      this.identifer = +new Date();
    }
  },
```

What we are doing here is we have added a key to the component, so when we change the key, the component will refresh.

Comment: I have also tried this, but the Sortablejs integrated with the component like below in mount is not longer working after refresh i.e., I cannot do drag and drop anymore `mounted () {
    let table = document.querySelector('.v-datatable tbody')
    console.log(table)
    const _self = this
    Sortable.create(table, {
      handle: ".handle",
      onEnd ({ newIndex, oldIndex }) {
        _self.$store.dispatch('adSets/updateAdSets', {oldIndex: oldIndex, newIndex: newIndex, orderId: _self.orderId, campaignId: _self.campaignId})
        _self.refreshComponent()
      }
    })
  }`

Comment: can you maybe provide the full code so that we can see why it is not working?